# SQL Query and Geolocation Coordinates

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I got into a heated argument the other day with a colleague and wanted to consult with the stackoverflow community which approach is feasible and even correct.

The first approach (my implemented solution) is the standard way of "drawing a circle" around some given coordinates and then query the database to retrieve all "markers" within a certain range, which ranges from 1 to 25 miles. This approach works, and gives accurate results, but sometimes is a bit slow when there are many "markers" in a dense area.

The approach by the colleague, is the following:
Take the given coordinates, round them up and down and query the database to find "close markers" and then perform another query with the above approach.

To make this a little clearer, let's say we have coordinates of -32.371267 and  115.827467. We would run a query to find the surrounding "markers" which are in -32 and 116 as well as 33 and 115.

I tried to argue that this is not possible and would result in slower performance because it requires an inner join than one large query, but as of now it still is unknown whether his implementation would even work.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Testing it is probably the best approach.  It seems like doing a rough estimate to pare down the results from everything in the database to those that are likely candidates could improve the performance, since many comparisons can be done with simpler logic and possibly indexed.  Then the complex distance logic would only be applied to a few rows.